# Rails NoMethodError: undefined method new for BigDecimal:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bigdecimal, oracle-call-interface

My app is on:

`ruby-2.6.4`
`Rails 4.2.8`
`activerecord-4.2.8`

I'm upgrading a rails app to `ruby-2.6.4`  When running a rake task in development, for testing, I am getting errors for `BigDecimal()` and `.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ruby-oci8/...`

```
ArgumentError: invalid value for BigDecimal(): "0.E+00"
/sha/git/sha_human_resources/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.8/lib/oci8/bindtype.rb:35:in `BigDecimal'
...
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.8/lib/oci8/bindtype.rb:216: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.8/lib/oci8/bindtype.rb:219: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.8/lib/oci8/compat.rb:73: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
```

I found a couple threads about updating the `bigdecimal` and `oci8` gems, so tried a couple versions and found these helped: `git diff Gemfile`:

```
-gem 'ruby-oci8', '~> 2.1.5'
+gem 'ruby-oci8', '~> 2.2.8'
```

and added a bigdecimal gem:

```
+gem "bigdecimal", ">= 2.0.0"
```

Now when I run my rake task, I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for BigDecimal:Class
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:111:in `<class:BigDecimal>'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:106:in `<top (required)>'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:3:in `require'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `require'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `require'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:7:in `require'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails.rb:11:in `require'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
.../config/application.rb:3:in `require'
.../config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
.../Rakefile:6:in `require'
.../Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.4/bin/bundle:30:in `block in <main>'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.4/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

Doing more Google surfing, I found there is not a lot of info on solving this.  I did see a couple mentions of upgrading to the latest version of rails.  Is this a must to solve this?  Is there a monkeypatch or fix out there that can solve/fix/prevent this until we are ready to upgrade our rails version?  I feel we will always be chasing the carrot-on-the-stick that is the latest version of rails.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 72):

As per [the documentation of BigDecimal](https://github.com/ruby/bigdecimal#which-version-should-you-select), for all Ruby versions 2.6.x, you should be using BigDecimal with a specific version:

> The differences among versions are given below:
>
> ```
> version  characteristics                                            Supported ruby version range
> 2.0.0    You cannot use BigDecimal.new and do subclassing           2.4 ..
> 1.4.x    BigDecimal.new and subclassing always prints warning.      2.3 .. 2.6
> 1.3.5    You can use BigDecimal.new and subclassing without warning .. 2.5
> ```
>
> You can select the version you want to use using `gem` method in Gemfile or scripts. For example, you want to stick bigdecimal version 1.3.5, it works file to put the following `gem` call in you Gemfile.
>
> ```
> gem 'bigdecimal', '1.3.5'
> ```

Comment: To reinforce the point, Rails 4 can't go higher than Ruby 2.6 nor can it go higher than BigDecimal 1.4.

Comment: For the record: I was able to run activerecord 4.2.11, bigdecimal 1.3.5 with ruby 2.7.5

Comment: For the record too, updating from Ruby 2.5.1 to Ruby 2.7.2, I fixed it adding shoulda-matchers 4.5.1, bigdecimal 1.3.5 and activerecord 4.2.11

Comment: I was also able to use Rails 4 with a Ruby higher than 2.6. My setup: Rails 4.2.11.3, Ruby 2.7.8 and bigdecimal 1.4.4