# Ruby on Rails: rails s or rails sever not working on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

**Here is my process**

What I tried:

- uninstalling & re-installing rails and railties
- updates rails from 4.2.5 > 4.2.8
- bundle install

As for the BigDecimal below, I have uninstalled it and re-installed the gem. I also changed the use of BigDecimal.new() to BigDecimal() as indicated when I researched this online.

`/Users/nahomie/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:111:in` class:BigDecimal': undefined method `new' for BigDecimal:Class (NoMethodError)`

**First I ran a bundle update, Results below: **

```
My First bundle update prior to my rails s command
nahomie@nahomie effort-forecaster % bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/...
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Using rake 13.0.6
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using minitest 5.15.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.9
Fetching activesupport 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Installing activesupport 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.7.1
Using racc 1.6.0
Using nokogiri 1.13.1
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.4
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.9
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.13.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
Fetching actionview 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Installing actionview 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Using rack 1.6.13
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Fetching actionpack 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Installing actionpack 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Using globalid 0.4.2
Fetching activejob 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Installing activejob 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Using mini_mime 1.1.2
Using mail 2.7.1
Fetching actionmailer 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Installing actionmailer 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using addressable 2.8.0
Fetching active_link_to 1.0.5 (was 1.0.3)
Installing active_link_to 1.0.5 (was 1.0.3)
Fetching activemodel 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Installing activemodel 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Using arel 6.0.4
Fetching activerecord 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Installing activerecord 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Fetching coderay 1.1.3 (was 1.1.0)
Installing coderay 1.1.3 (was 1.1.0)
Fetching erubi 1.10.0
Installing erubi 1.10.0
Fetching better_errors 2.9.1 (was 2.1.1)
Installing better_errors 2.9.1 (was 2.1.1)
Fetching debug_inspector 1.1.0 (was 0.0.2)
Installing debug_inspector 1.1.0 (was 0.0.2) with native extensions
Fetching binding_of_caller 1.0.0 (was 0.7.2)
Installing binding_of_caller 1.0.0 (was 0.7.2)
Fetching bootstrap_form 2.7.0 (was 2.3.0)
Installing bootstrap_form 2.7.0 (was 2.3.0)
Using bundler 2.0.0.pre.3
Fetching byebug 11.1.3 (was 8.2.0)
Installing byebug 11.1.3 (was 8.2.0) with native extensions
Fetching cancancan 3.3.0 (was 1.13.1)
Installing cancancan 3.3.0 (was 1.13.1)
Fetching chartkick 4.1.3 (was 1.4.1)
Installing chartkick 4.1.3 (was 1.4.1)
Fetching chunky_png 1.4.0 (was 1.3.5)
Installing chunky_png 1.4.0 (was 1.3.5)
Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2 (was 1.10.0)
Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2 (was 1.10.0)
Fetching execjs 2.8.1 (was 2.6.0)
Installing execjs 2.8.1 (was 2.6.0)
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 1.2.1
Fetching railties 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Installing railties 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Fetching coffee-rails 4.1.1 (was 4.1.0)
Installing coffee-rails 4.1.1 (was 4.1.0)
Fetching connection_pool 2.2.5 (was 2.2.0)
Installing connection_pool 2.2.5 (was 2.2.0)
Using declarative 0.0.20
Fetching unf_ext 0.0.8 (was 0.0.7.1)
Installing unf_ext 0.0.8 (was 0.0.7.1) with native extensions
Using unf 0.1.4
Fetching domain_name 0.5.20190701 (was 0.5.24)
Installing domain_name 0.5.20190701 (was 0.5.24)
Fetching faker 2.2.1 (was 1.6.1)
Installing faker 2.2.1 (was 1.6.1)
Using faraday-em_http 1.0.0
Using faraday-em_synchrony 1.0.0
Using faraday-excon 1.1.0
Using faraday-httpclient 1.0.1
Using multipart-post 2.1.1
Using faraday-multipart 1.0.3
Using faraday-net_http 1.0.1
Using faraday-net_http_persistent 1.2.0
Using faraday-patron 1.0.0
Using faraday-rack 1.0.0
Using faraday-retry 1.0.3
Using ruby2_keywords 0.0.5
Using faraday 1.9.3
Using ffi 1.15.5
Fetching font-awesome-rails 4.7.0.8 (was 4.4.0.0)
Installing font-awesome-rails 4.7.0.8 (was 4.4.0.0)
Fetching formatador 1.0.0 (was 0.2.5)
Installing formatador 1.0.0 (was 0.2.5)
Using friendly_id 5.0.5
Using jwt 2.3.0 (was 2.2.2)
Using memoist 0.16.2
Using multi_json 1.15.0
Using os 1.1.4
Using signet 0.16.0
Using googleauth 0.17.1
Using httpclient 2.8.3
Using trailblazer-option 0.1.2
Using uber 0.1.0
Using representable 3.1.1
Using retriable 3.1.2
Using rexml 3.2.5
Using google-api-client 0.52.0
Fetching groupdate 4.1.2 (was 2.4.0)
Installing groupdate 4.1.2 (was 2.4.0)
Fetching rb-fsevent 0.11.0 (was 0.9.6)
Installing rb-fsevent 0.11.0 (was 0.9.6)
Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.1 (was 0.9.5)
Installing rb-inotify 0.10.1 (was 0.9.5)
Fetching listen 3.7.1 (was 3.0.5)
Installing listen 3.7.1 (was 3.0.5)
Fetching lumberjack 1.2.8 (was 1.0.9)
Installing lumberjack 1.2.8 (was 1.0.9)
Fetching nenv 0.3.0 (was 0.2.0)
Installing nenv 0.3.0 (was 0.2.0)
Using shellany 0.0.1
Fetching notiffany 0.1.3 (was 0.0.8)
Installing notiffany 0.1.3 (was 0.0.8)
Fetching method_source 1.0.0 (was 0.8.2)
Installing method_source 1.0.0 (was 0.8.2)
Fetching pry 0.14.1 (was 0.10.3)
Installing pry 0.14.1 (was 0.10.3)
Fetching guard 2.18.0 (was 2.13.0)
Installing guard 2.18.0 (was 2.13.0)
Using guard-compat 1.2.1
Fetching guard-minitest 2.4.6 (was 2.4.4)
Installing guard-minitest 2.4.6 (was 2.4.4)
Fetching temple 0.8.2
Installing temple 0.8.2
Fetching tilt 2.0.10 (was 2.0.1)
Installing tilt 2.0.10 (was 2.0.1)
Fetching haml 5.2.2 (was 4.0.7)
Installing haml 5.2.2 (was 4.0.7)
Fetching hashie 5.0.0 (was 3.6.0)
Installing hashie 5.0.0 (was 3.6.0)
Fetching http-cookie 1.0.4 (was 1.0.2)
Installing http-cookie 1.0.4 (was 1.0.2)
Fetching jbuilder 2.9.1 (was 2.3.2)
Installing jbuilder 2.9.1 (was 2.3.2)
Fetching jquery-rails 4.4.0 (was 4.0.5)
Installing jquery-rails 4.4.0 (was 4.0.5)
Using json 2.6.1 (was 1.8.6)
Using mime-types 2.99.3
Fetching mini_magick 4.11.0 (was 4.2.7)
Installing mini_magick 4.11.0 (was 4.2.7)
Fetching multi_xml 0.6.0 (was 0.5.5)
Installing multi_xml 0.6.0 (was 0.5.5)
Fetching netrc 0.11.0 (was 0.10.3)
Installing netrc 0.11.0 (was 0.10.3)
Fetching nio4r 2.5.8
Installing nio4r 2.5.8 with native extensions
Fetching oauth2 1.4.7 (was 1.4.4)
Installing oauth2 1.4.7 (was 1.4.4)
Using omniauth 1.9.1
Fetching omniauth-oauth2 1.7.2 (was 1.7.0)
Installing omniauth-oauth2 1.7.2 (was 1.7.0)
Fetching omniauth-github 1.4.0 (was 1.1.2)
Installing omniauth-github 1.4.0 (was 1.1.2)
Fetching omniauth-google-oauth2 0.8.2 (was 0.8.0)
Installing omniauth-google-oauth2 0.8.2 (was 0.8.0)
Fetching ruby-openid 2.9.2 (was 2.7.0)
Installing ruby-openid 2.9.2 (was 2.7.0)
Fetching rack-openid 1.4.2 (was 1.3.1)
Installing rack-openid 1.4.2 (was 1.3.1)
Fetching omniauth-openid 2.0.1 (was 1.0.1)
Installing omniauth-openid 2.0.1 (was 1.0.1)
Fetching pg 1.3.0 (was 0.18.4)
Installing pg 1.3.0 (was 0.18.4) with native extensions
Fetching pry-rails 0.3.9 (was 0.3.4)
Installing pry-rails 0.3.9 (was 0.3.4)
Fetching puma 5.5.2 (was 2.15.3)
Installing puma 5.5.2 (was 2.15.3) with native extensions
Using quiet_assets 1.1.0
Fetching rack-protection 1.5.5 (was 1.5.3)
Installing rack-protection 1.5.5 (was 1.5.3)
Using sprockets 3.7.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.2
Fetching rails 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Installing rails 4.2.8 (was 4.2.5)
Fetching rails-assets-bootstrap 5.1.3 (was 3.3.5)
Installing rails-assets-bootstrap 5.1.3 (was 3.3.5)
Fetching rails-assets-jquery 3.6.0 (was 2.1.4)
Installing rails-assets-jquery 3.6.0 (was 2.1.4)
Fetching rails-assets-datatables 1.10.21 (was 1.10.10)
Installing rails-assets-datatables 1.10.21 (was 1.10.10)
Fetching rails-assets-datatables-fixedcolumns 4.0.1 (was 3.2.0)
Installing rails-assets-datatables-fixedcolumns 4.0.1 (was 3.2.0)
Fetching rails-assets-handlebars 4.1.2 (was 4.0.5)
Installing rails-assets-handlebars 4.1.2 (was 4.0.5)
Fetching rails-assets-jasny-bootstrap 3.2.0 (was 3.1.3)
Installing rails-assets-jasny-bootstrap 3.2.0 (was 3.1.3)
Using rails-assets-typeahead.js 0.11.1
Fetching rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5 (was 0.0.4)
Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5 (was 0.0.4)
Fetching rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5 (was 0.0.4)
Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5 (was 0.0.4)
Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
Fetching ransack 1.8.10 (was 1.7.0)
Installing ransack 1.8.10 (was 1.7.0)
Fetching rdiscount 2.2.0.2 (was 2.1.8)
Installing rdiscount 2.2.0.2 (was 2.1.8) with native extensions
Fetching rdoc 6.3.3 (was 6.4)
Installing rdoc 6.3.3 (was 6.4)
Fetching redis 4.5.1 (was 3.2.2)
Installing redis 4.5.1 (was 3.2.2)
Using rest-client 1.8.0
Fetching sinatra 1.4.8 (was 1.4.6)
Installing sinatra 1.4.8 (was 1.4.6)
Fetching refile 0.6.2 (was 0.6.1)
Installing refile 0.6.2 (was 0.6.1)
Fetching refile-mini_magick 0.2.0 (was 0.1.0)
Installing refile-mini_magick 0.2.0 (was 0.1.0)
Fetching ruby_identicon 0.0.6 (was 0.0.4)
Installing ruby_identicon 0.0.6 (was 0.0.4)
Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
Fetching sass 3.7.4 (was 3.4.19)
Installing sass 3.7.4 (was 3.4.19)
Fetching sass-rails 5.0.7 (was 5.0.4)
Installing sass-rails 5.0.7 (was 5.0.4)
Using sdoc 2.3.0
Fetching sidekiq 5.2.8 (was 4.0.1)
Installing sidekiq 5.2.8 (was 4.0.1)
Fetching simple_form 4.0.0 (was 3.1.1)
Installing simple_form 4.0.0 (was 3.1.1)
Fetching spring 3.1.1 (was 1.4.4)
Installing spring 3.1.1 (was 1.4.4)
Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Fetching turbolinks 5.2.1 (was 2.5.3)
Installing turbolinks 5.2.1 (was 2.5.3)
Fetching uglifier 4.2.0 (was 2.7.2)
Installing uglifier 4.2.0 (was 2.7.2)
Fetching web-console 2.3.0 (was 2.2.1)
Installing web-console 2.3.0 (was 2.2.1)
Bundle updated!
Post-install message from rails-assets-bootstrap:
This component doesn't define main assets in bower.json.
Please open new pull request in component's repository:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap
Post-install message from sass:

Ruby Sass has reached end-of-life and should no longer be used.

* If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
  primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install

* If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
  sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme

* For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
  https://sass-lang.com/blog/posts/7828841
```

**Current Error below that persist when I run rails s**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    22: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    21: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    20: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    18: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:73:in `server'
    17: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
    16: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require'
    15: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `require'
    13: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails.rb:11:in `require'
    11: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:7:in `require'
     9: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `require'
     7: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
     5: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `require'
     3: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:3:in `require'
     1: from /Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:106:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/nay/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:111:in `<class:BigDecimal>': undefined method `new' for BigDecimal:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is duplicated with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60226893/rails-nomethoderror-undefined-method-new-for-bigdecimalclass)
I'll put adil's answer below.

According to the [the documentation of BigDecimal](https://github.com/ruby/bigdecimal#which-version-should-you-select), for all Ruby versions 2.6.x, you should be using BigDecimal with a specific version:

> The differences among versions are given below:
>
> ```
> version characteristics                                           Supported ruby version range
> 3.0.0   You can use BigDecimal with Ractor on Ruby 3.0             2.5 ..
> 2.0.x   You cannot use BigDecimal.new and do subclassing           2.4 ..
> 1.4.x   BigDecimal.new and subclassing always prints warning.      2.3 .. 2.7
> 1.3.5   You can use BigDecimal.new and subclassing without warning .. 2.5
> ```

try putting this in your gem file.

```
gem 'bigdecimal', '~> 1.4' 
or
gem 'bigdecimal', '1.3.5'
```